# which loop in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, aix

I am quite new in bash, but I need to create a simple script which will do below steps:

Wait 1 minute

A) bash script will use CM to generate result file

B) check row 8 in result file (to know if Administrator is running any jobs or not)

if NO jobs:

C) bash script will use CM to start cube refresh

D) wait 1 minute

D1) Remove result file

E) generate result file

E1) Read row 8

no jobs:
         F) remove result file  G) EXIT

yes:

I) Go to D)

YES:

E) Wait 1 minute

F) Remove result file

Go to A)

As bash doesn't have goto (or should not be use), I tried few loops, but I not sure which I should choose.

I know how to:
- start cube(step C)
- generate result file (step A & E):
- check line 8: 
sed '8!d' /abc_uat/cmlogs/adm_jobs_u1.log 
condition for loops will be probably similar to this: !='Owner = Administrator'

but how to avoid goto ?

I tried with while do loop, but I am not sure what should I add in case of false condition, I added else, but not sure of it:

```
sleep 60
Generate result file with admin jobs (which admin runs inside of 3rd party tool)

while [ sed '8!d' admin_jobs_result_file.log !="Owner = Administrator" ];
 do
--NO Admin jobs
    START CUBE REFRESH (it will start admin job)
    sleep 60
    REMOVE RESULT FILE (OLD)
    GENERATE RESULT FILE
    while [ sed '8!d' admin_jobs_result_file.log = "Owner = Administrator" ];
 --Admin is still running cube refresh
    do 
    sleep 60    
    REMOVE RESULT FILE (OLD)
    GENERATE RESULT FILE
-- it should continue checking every 1 minute if admin is still running cube refresh job, so I hope it will go back to while condition
    else
    done
else
-- Admin is running something
sleep 60    
REMOVE RESULT FILE (OLD)
GENERATE RESULT FILE
-it should check result file again but I think it will finish loop
done
```

Comment: Please use Markdown lists to make that outline readable.

Comment: Sounds like you either have many questions or are simply requesting code.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace goto with a loop. while loop, for example.

**Syntax**

```
while <condition>
do
    action
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [cron jobs](http://ss64.com/bash/crontab.html). Delegate, if possible, "waiting for a minute" task to cron. Cron should worry about running your script on a timely fashion.

You may consider writing two scripts instead of one.

Do you really need to create a result file? Do you know [piping](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html) ? (no offense, just mentioning it because you said you were fairly new to bash)

Comment: We cannot use cron as script will be started on request. We use autosys system which starts this script when needed.

Comment: we have to wait (sleep 60) for time to time, to be sure that some processes on 3party tool are started. In that tool we are checking if jobs are running (these are not aix/system jobs), so yes, we need to have result file to know if inside this application any jobs are running or not.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is self explanatory.

```
result_file=admin_jobs_result_file.log

function generate {
    logmsg sleeping
    sleep 60
    rm -f "$result_file"
    logmsg generating
    # use CM to generate result file 
}

function owner_is_administrator {
    # if line 8 contains "Owner = Administrator", exit success
    # else exit failure
    sed -n '8 {/Owner = Administrator/ q 0; q 1}' "$result_file"
}

function logmsg { date "+%Y-%m-%d %T -- $*"; }

##############
generate

while owner_is_administrator; do
    generate
done

# at this point, line 8 does NOT contain "Owner = Administrator"

logmsg start cube refresh
# use CM to start cube refresh

generate

while owner_is_administrator; do
    generate
done

logmsg Done
```

Looks like AIX's sed can't exit with a specified status. Try this instead:

```
function owner_is_administrator {
    # if line 8 contains "Owner = Administrator", exit success
    # else exit failure
    awk 'NR == 8 {if (/Owner = Administrator/) {exit 0} else {exit 1}}' "$result_file"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand...most ;) If Administrator run any job, will it wait (and check status every 1 minute) ? or just exit ? In general we want to keep script in executing state when Admin is running anything. Thanks to it some autosys jobs will know that should not start other processes.

Comment: I run a script, but I have this error:     sed: Function 8 {/Owner = Administrator/ q 0; q 1} cannot be parsed.

Comment: Perfect! It is working now. I will do some additional tests, but looks very promising. Many thanks for such quick help.

Comment: When servers are working as cluster, information about jobs which Admin is running may also be in line 15 (admin jobs from second node). So I need to check if Owner=Administrator is in line 8 and in line 15. I modified awk to:       awk '/Owner = Administrator/{if (NR == 8 || NR==15) {exit 0} else {exit 1}}' "$result_file" - but it returns nothing (nor 0 nor 1) if Owner = Administrator is not in a result file at all.